# Convert Nota Bene 4 to LaTeX

Tags: conversion

My wife has an old manuscript in Nota Bene 4 (for DOS, which tells you how old it is). I'm able to look at the files with BBEDIT, so I know they are basically in ASCII with alphanumeric markup. Does anyone know of a utility for converting Nota Bene 4 files to LaTeX?

Unfortunately, I don't have access to any computer that runs either Nota Bene 4 for DOS or the more recent Windows versions.

Comment: As near as I can tell, the .nb format is undocumented and no converters for it exist. Your best hope would be to write something yourself. or depending on the length of the document, use search and replace to manually convert it.

Comment: Yes, I think I could do this if I had to. I also notice that Nota Bene runs on the Mac now, and I may just buy it for my wife and have her convert it to a more current version of NB. I think NB will output docx, so conceivably that would give me a route to turn it to LaTeX via pandoc. I was wondering whether there might be some more direct route.

Comment: Documentation on Nota Bene is sparse. Even its markup is very cryptic. Googling some sources, one find things like `®SZ14PT` (14pt, maybe?) for Nota Bene 8 files. If you have any example, even minimal, of a processed file, it may be a nice starting point.

Comment: Actually, there is a package at CTAN `nb4latex` by one Guido Milanese. Might do what you need, even though it seems old and probably unsupported.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to convert NB files? I'm looking to do the same thing with an old paper by my advisor.